# Ошибка syntax error в Termux

Tags: android, консоль, sh, termux

При любом действии с `pkg` в Termux происходит ошибка:

```
$ pkg update
Checking availability of current mirror: bad
Testing the available mirrors:
[*] https://mirror.mwt.me/termux/main: ok
[*] https://termux.sahilister.in/apt/termux-main: ok
[*] https://plug-mirror.rcac.purdue.edu/termux/termux-main: ok
[*] https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-main: ok
[*] https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24: ok
[*] https://termux.librehat.com/apt/termux-main: ok
[*] https://termux.astra.in.ua/apt/termux-main: ok
[*] https://packages-cf.termux.org/apt/termux-main: ok
[*] https://dl.kcubeterm.com/termux-main: ok
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/pkg: line 142: 7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
16: syntax error in expression (error token is "8
9
10
11
12
13
14
16")
$
```

Что это может быть и как это исправить?
Termux установлен из F-Droid, последняя версия 0.118.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для начала вводишь:
`termux-change-repo`
выбираешь все три варианта и меняешь на GitHub
[image]

нажимаешь enter и всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало! Установил себе Xfce4 и VNC, теперь пользуюсь этим "компьютером" :)